# $http request in Angular 1.1.4

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, angularjs-directive

I have a list where you can pull down to refresh. This event is fired inside a directive that handles the detection of the pullable list, the element looks like this.

```
<div class="pull-to-refresh" pulldown="update()">
    //The list goes here
</div>
```

So in the directive, I detect the pulldown movement (with iscroll) and when released I call the function:

```
function pullDownAction(){
    scope.$eval(attr.pulldown);
}
```

The update() function in the controller looks like this:

```
$scope.update = function () {
    $http.get('/myurl/')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.model = data;
        });
};
```

Since updating from angular 1.1.1 to 1.1.4, the request no longer gets made. The function is called, but the request is not made. However, I can call the update() function straight from the view and it works, like so:

```
<button ng-click="update()">Click to update</button>
```

But, when called from the directive, it goes into the function, but the request is not made. I have looked through the changelog, but havent found anything that would cause this behaviour, and it works fine in angular 1.1.1. Does anyone have a clue as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.1.4 currently requires to do the `$http.get` in `$scope.$apply` (don't know this is a bug).
since `ng-click` does `$scope.apply` for you, in your directive you have to do this manualy.
AFAIK scope.$eval does not trigger $digest, so try `$scope.$apply(attrs.pulldown)`;

Comment: Well, it did work. Haven't read about it somewhere else though, so I don't know if it's a bug either ;)